# Imagine if open() method threw exception ignore then proceed to the next loop

Tags: php, batch-file, image-processing, php-imagine

I am trying to use [Imagine](http://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to batch make 250x250 thumbnail of more than 90k+ relatively small mobile images. The problem is, when I run a loop,

```
foreach ($images as $c) {
  $imagine = new Imagine();
  $image = $imagine->open($c);
  $image->resize(new Box(250, 250))->save($outFolder);
}
```

sometimes, the image is corrupted and the `open()` method fails, throwing exception:

`Unable to open image
vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php
Line: 96`

and completely breaks the loop. Is there a way, to check if `open` failed? something like:

```
foreach ($images as $c) {
  $imagine = new Imagine();
  $image = $imagine->open($c);
  if ($image) {
     $image->resize(new Box(250, 250))->save($outFolder);
  } else {
     echo 'corrupted: <br />';
  }
}
```

Hope somebody can help. or if its not possible, can you suggest a PHP image library that I can pragmatically resize by batch?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling the exception just use `try-catch`.

From the library [documentation](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/introduction.html#open-existing-images)

> The ImagineInterface::open() method may throw one of the following exceptions:
>
> > **Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException**
> >
> > **Imagine\Exception\RuntimeException**

Try it like this:

```
$imagine = new Imagine(); // Probably no need to instantiate it in every loop
foreach ($images as $c) {
    try {
        $image = $imagine->open($c);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo 'corrupted: <br />';
        continue;
    }
    $image->resize(new Box(250, 250))->save($outFolder);
}
```

Comment: thank you! This is actually my first real life use of exception.